# Lua find number of occurences of searched string

Tags: linux, lua, window-management

I'm trying to count and print out the numeric value of how many times the "terminator" value has been outputted. Is there any function that does this? If not how should i tackle this problem?

```
output = get_application_name()
var = string.match("terminator", get_application_name())
print(var)
```

I would like to count

```
nil
terminator
nil
nil
terminaor
```

Comment: Is this homework? It's not against policies, but the premise simply is different, often you are supposed to solve a problem in a certain way - like using loops. Please also check [help/on-topic].

Comment: @dualed No, its not a homework. I'm trying to improve window management on my linux box, and for that i need to find out how many instances of the same application are running. I just wanted to find out what would be the best way to go about it, since im not experienced with lua scripting

Comment: Then you should absolutely add the window manager in question as a tag, this will attract the crowd you may be looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [`string.gsub`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-string.gsub) function. From the docs:

> `gsub` also returns, as its second value, the total number of matches
>   that occurred.

So:

```
output = get_application_name()
_, count = output:gsub("terminator", '')
print(output)
```

Comment: Can terminator string be `$` ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff of course not. But for special characters, OP would have to escape them anyhow. Given the information, gsub suits the OP best.

Comment: `_, count = output:gsub(("terminator"):gsub("%p", "%%%0"), "")`

Comment: Based on the displayed output, i should create a for loop to go through the output and add up how many times the pattern has been displayed, and then print out the numeric value